# Why is observablecollection initialized to null?

Tags: c#

I used this constructor to initialize this object

```
 ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

It turned out that allTabs was null after initialization. I couldn't add MyHomeworkModel objects to it because of that.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MyHomework;

namespace MyHomework__MVVM_
{
    class MyHomeworkViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs;
        private MyHomeworkModel selectedTab;

        public MyHomeworkViewModel()
        {
            ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
            selectedTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
            AddCourseCommand = new AddCourseCommand(this);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> AllTabs
        {
            get
            {
                return allTabs;
            }
            set
            {
                allTabs = value;
            }
        }

        public MyHomeworkModel SelectedTab
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedTab;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedTab = value;
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddCourseCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void AddNewTab()
        {
            NewCourseName ncn = new NewCourseName();
            ncn.ShowDialog();
            if (ncn.courseName != null)
            {
                MyHomeworkModel newTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
                newTab.Header = ncn.courseName;
                AllTabs.Add(newTab);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you look on the **same** objects. Cound be that there are more then one allTabs objects in your application ?

Comment: Try to Create a Property to this Variable and that set a breakpoint into the Setter, than look where it runs into after setting to Null

Comment: I think you're missing something where allTabs is changed. Following that code _in isolation_, allTabs will **not** be null.

Comment: Is your executed code being executed???

Comment: A quick debug session should have spotted this immediately, i.e. you should have looked at the value after it is initialized in your constructor and afterwords, you would have seen two separate objects named `allTabs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public MyHomeworkViewModel()
    {
        allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
        selectedTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
        AddCourseCommand = new AddCourseCommand(this);
    }
```

Comment: What a dumb mistake! I can't believe that XD Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here(in the constructor of `MyHomeworkViewModel`):

```
ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

You create a local variable that shadows the class member and thus it remains null after the constructor call. To avoid that simply skip the type at the beginning of the statement:

```
allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of the explenation

Answer (score 1):

If you create

```
ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

In your Constructor, it will be removed after run out of it. Declare it outside and that call just

```
allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

Comment: He is declaring it outside of the constructor, he's just shadowing it in the constructor with a local.

Comment: Yes thats right, but he Never create an Instance of the Membervariable and thats the point!

Comment: You state that he should declare it outside of the constructor, but he's already doing that, that's my point.  He needs to initialize the field that he has already declared, and your first 3 edits didn't state that.

Answer (score 0):

The line `ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();` is **not** setting the `allTabs` *field* to a new collection, it's creating a new local variable and setting that local variable to a new collection.  To initialize the field you should change that line to:

```
allTabs = new ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel>();
```

Comment: I'd advise using `this.allTabs` so it's clear which scope the variable is in.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Well, here he shouldn't have *any* locals, since none are needed, so there shouldn't be anything to confuse it with.  The idea of using `this.` for all field access is a convention that some like, and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

This is one reason for the C# convention of prefixing private class variables with an underscore:

`private ObservableCollection<MyHomeworkModel> _allTabs;`

More guidelines here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: 1) doing that wouldn't prevent him from shadowing it if he still uses the type in the constructor 2) it's not nearly as common of a convention in C# as in VB.  VB uses it more since it can't rely on case sensitivity.  3) your link doesn't encourage that practice.